# Custom Control is Spitting out it's name into the Source!

Tags: asp.net

No idea why but when I place my custom control in my .aspx page, it's rendering the ID out also.  So Consequently, I'm writing out some JavaScript to the page also and right in the middle I get this name of my control so it's messing up my JavaScript.

So in my .aspx I have:

```
<pm:Car ID="ProductCar" runat="server"/>
```

And here's what starts to get rendered:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ctl00_mainContent_ProductCar
lastProductID;var ctl00_mainContent_ProductCar
carSize;
...
```

as you can see ctl00_mainContent_ProductCar is the ID and it's being rendered right after var so I end up with a lastProductID not found error in my JavaScript because the text ctl00_mainContent_ProductCa is in the way.

(updated)

```
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write(BuildCarJavaScript());
    }
```

simply outputs a bunch of JavaScript to the page.  And nowhere in my JavaScript do I have it just outputting clientID by itself like I'm seeing.

In BuildCarJavaScript here is where I'm creating that code:

```
        carJavaScript.Append(@"<script type=""text/javascript"">" + "\r\n");
        carJavaScript.AppendFormat("var {0}lastProductID;", this.ClientID + "\r\n");
...
```

Comment: You'll need to provide the Render code of the custom control in order to help figure out what the problem may be.

Comment: Maybe I should've been more specific, if you could post the code that renders, say, the "var .... LastProductID", that would be helpful.

Comment: Just edited the initial post.  It's there now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you expected.  This line:

```
carJavaScript.AppendFormat("var {0}lastProductID;", this.ClientID + "\r\n");
```

Is going to produce exactly what you're seeing.  I guess it might be better to ask; what did you want this to produce?

Comment: oh sh** I finally see it now.. I wanted to append a line return AFTER the variable.  Duh.

Comment: here we go: carJavaScript.AppendFormat("var {0}lastProductID;", this.ClientID).Append("\r\n");  Did not know I could/should chain it like this

Comment: lol - happens to the best of us.  sometimes it takes laying it out to someone else too see what's wrong.